# Getting data from PHP Object with Colons and Slashes in Name

Tags: php

Im new to Objects and have some basic understanding, but struggling with getting data from a particular type of node.

This:

```
$test->broadcast_data
```

Returns:

```
object(threewp_broadcast\BroadcastData)#1599 (5) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(49663)
  ["blog_id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["post_id"]=>
  int(38863)
  ["dataModified":"threewp_broadcast\broadcast_data":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["data":"threewp_broadcast\broadcast_data":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["version"]=>
    int(2)
    ["linked_children"]=>
    array(3) {
      [2]=>
      int(18557)
      [3]=>
      int(8097)
      [4]=>
      int(1768)
    }
  }
}
```

I know i can get the ID by doing:

```
$test->broadcast_data->id
```

But how do i get the `linked_children` array and assign it to a variable.  The colon and slashes in `"data":"threewp_broadcast\broadcast_data":private` is throwing me off.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the property is `data`. The colons and slashes that you're seeing is not part of the property of the class.

```
"data":"threewp_broadcast\broadcast_data":private
```

The `threewp_broadcast\broadcast_data` represents the namespace and class that the property belongs to and the `:private` means that the `data` property is `private`, therefore you cannot access it without a class method.

You can look in the class file to see if there's a function like `getData()` which would return the value of the private property.

For example, a class like the following:

```
namespace A;

class B{
    private $test;   
}
```

And the dump of it would give the following:

```
object(A\B)#1 (1) {
  ["test":"A\B":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

As you can see `"test":"A\B":private` is not the name of the property.

### Update

After looking in the class [threewp_broadcast\broadcast_data](https://github.com/wp-plugins/threewp-broadcast/blob/master/src/broadcast_data.php), there is a function named `getData()` so you could do:

```
$test->broadcast_data->getData()['linked_children'];
```

Or simply use the function `get_linked_children()` provided by the class:

```
$test->broadcast_data->get_linked_children();
```

Comment: Good job for extra research!

Comment: Oh wow  this is an awesome answer and i got it!  thanks for the extra research.  I went and looked all over the place for that. youre the best!

Comment: @Joe No problem :)